# Solve for ellipse given axis-parallel tangent line and another tangent line

Tags: conic-sections

See illustration I know point $P_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ which sits on a line $L_1$. $P_1$ will lie on the semi-minor axis. $L_1$ is parallel to the semi-major axis. Have another line $L_2$ which is tangent to the ellipse elsewhere in the first or fourth quadrants. I know a point $P_2 = (x_2,y_2)$ on this line which should also lie on the ellipse.[image: Ellipse Problem]

$P_1$, $P_2$, $L_1$, $L_2$ are all known. My problem is how do I find $a$ and $b$, the length of the semi-major and semi-minor axes? My intuition tells me my problem is constrained enough to be solved to a single ellipse.

I started with the Cartestian equation for an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, did some implicit differentiation to get $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-xb^2}{ya^2}$. I know the slope of the tangent line $L_2$, so thought this would be the best line of attack but have been staring at this ages now and don't know how to proceed. What I'm looking to get is two **linear** equations with $a$ and $b$ in them, right?

I went down the path of rearranging the derivative equation. I've substituted $m_2$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$; the slope of $L_2$:

$$a = \sqrt{\frac{-x_2b^2}{y_2m_2}}$$

but don't see how this helps me because it's not a linear equation. How can I solve for my ellipse?

EDIT: I used the equation of an ellipse centred at the origin above, but this was a mistake. I'm happy to rotate/translate lines to make the calculations simpler and then transform back e.g. so that $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: If you can upload an illustration it would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @samjoe I was too eager with the "Post" button. Illustration now uploaded.

Comment: Do you know all $P_1, P_2, L_1, L_2$ ?

Comment: @samjoe yes, they're known.

Comment: The form of your ellipse's equation implies that the center is at $(0,0)$ and $|y_1|=b$, $x_1=0$. If that is not given, you have to modify the ellipse's equation.

Comment: @ccorn That's a good point. The ellipse isn't centred at the origin.

Comment: Also $m_1=0$ in that setting. If that is not the case, you'll have to rotate the ellipse as well, or use the general algebraic form of the conic section equation.

Comment: @ccorn To simplify things I was going to rotate the lines to make $L_1$  parallel to the x-axis, solve, then rotate back.

Comment: OK, then $m_1=0$. Have you also translated such that $x_1=0$? Then you only need a $y_0$ coordinate for the center.

Comment: @ccorn I hadn't thought about that, but could do the translation so $x_1 = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not actually have the ellipse's center given, you need a more general form for the ellipse's equation.

Here is a geometric **hint**; I leave it to you to translate this to algebra.

You know the minor symmetry axis of the ellipse:
It is the line orthogonal to $L_1$ passing through $P_1$.
Now all you need to determine the center $O$ is another non-parallel line
known to pass through $O$.
Let $M$ be the midpoint between $P_1$ and $P_2$.
Let $Q$ be the intersection point of $L_1$ and $L_2$.
Then the straight line $MQ$ passes through $O$.

[image: Ellipse with tangents]

Why? Because that would be the case if the ellipse were a circle.
Deforming a circle into an arbitrary ellipse can be done with an
invertible affine transformation.
Such transformations preserve line straightness, tangency and midpoint
relationships.
Therefore $MQ$ still passes through $O$ after the transformation.

Comment: Plugged this in and works a treat :) I like your reasoning about the transformation preserving midpoint relationships, etc. BTW, did you use a particular program to generate your drawing? I would like an alternative to uploading images.

Comment: @PeteUK: The figure has been generated with an older, Java-based, desktop version of [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org).

Comment: Nice answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $P_1=(0,b)$ and $P_2=(a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)=(h,k)$, both lying on the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, and that $L_1: y=b$, and $L_2: x+By+C=0\tag{1}$.

Quantities $b,h,k,B,C$ are known. 
We only need to find the value of $a$ to determine the ellipse.

First we can determine $\theta$ as equating $k=b\sin\theta$, and consequently determine a using $h=a\cos\theta$.

By differentiating and using standard formulas, we find that the equation of the tangent at $P$ is

$$\frac x{a\sin\theta}+\frac y{b\cos\theta}-(\tan\theta+\cot\theta)=0$$
which can be written as

$$x+\left(\frac ab\tan\theta\right)y-a\sin\theta(\tan\theta+\cot\theta)=0\tag{2} $$

Using values of $a,\theta$ as computed, coefficients in equations $(1),(2)$ should turn out to be equal.

Comment: Does this answer assume the ellipse is centred at the origin? It isn't. I've updated my answer to show that. Doesn't that now mean that $h$ and $k$ are unknown? Is $C$ also unknown in equation of $L_2$? Is equation of $L_2$ missing the coefficient on $x$? How come $P_1 = (0,-b)$? Shouldn't it's y-value by positive if it's above the ellipse's centre?

Comment: It assumes that the method applies after you have done the translation such that $x_1=0$. $h,k$ are known as question specifies both points are known. Both $B, C$ are known as question specifies both lines are known. No coeff for $x$, as other coeffs assumed to be normalised. Works for both $P_1=(0,-b), L_1: y=-b$ as well as $P_1=(0,b), L_1: y=b$. Now changed to the latter for greater clarity.